# I have lost All my contact on Samsung Galaxy S GT I9000

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

Yesterday I have lost all the contacts on my GT-I9000. The device was left alone for 5 minutes & when I checked it again for some work, I found that the contact numbers had been lost & I am not able to find them.
Is this a common problem with GT-I9000? Is there any way to get the contacts back?

Comment: Weird, this happened to a friend of mine too, just yesterday...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you lost them or if its a common problem. But you definitely can get back the lost contacts provided they were synced with Google Contacts(not SIM contacts).

First try to sync and see if contacts come back. If we cleared data of "Contact Storage" from Manage Applications, all the synced contacts in phone will disappear until you sync back again.

If that doesn't help, Google Contacts fortunately has restore option. Open Gmail, go to Contacts, Select More and select Restore contacts.

Comment: I also lost the contacts yesterday on a Samsung Galaxy S, because I thought they were synced to Google (the sync setting was active, and showed it was done) and re-installed the OS (hoping to get the contacts back from Google). But it turned out they had not been saved on Google (although no errors were reported). Perhaps, this is similar to the sync to Picasa problem which is reported to happen when you have also connected to your Facebook etc. accounts, no?